# Mesh editing via SceneKit

Tags: swift, stl, scenekit

This is my first post here. Hope I won't make any mistake...

I'm actually trying to manipulate a STL mesh file inside a `SCNView` through the model I/O framework.

I can't find any documentation or tutorial about mesh editing (cutting, cropping,...) directly via the `SCNView`. Most of the comments I have seen resolve this by using an external mesh editor (Blender, Meshmixer,...).

Do you know if there any tools or a way to allow mesh editing directly through the app?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. You'll have to implement all of the functionality you need yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you have any idea how i should proceed or documentation i should read ? Thanks again

Comment: That sort of question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. The Chris Language book is pretty good for getting started, and David Rönnqvist's book deals with meshes a bit. Watch all of the WWDC videos and study their sample code. Without knowing what you're trying to build, and how far you've gone, nobody can say more. SO is good for specific programming questions but not for this sort of thing. BTW, use upvotes; don't add "thank you" messages.